# Problems with using an aggregate function

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I am trying to take individual values, and divide them by their sum within a column.

I.e.

```
SELECT (column1 / SUM(column1))
FROM Table a
```

This works just fine, but when i include another necessary piece of information...

```
SELECT column2
      ,(column1 / SUM(column1)) 
FROM Table a
```

Then it returns Column1 is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Then if i include column2 within the group by clause, my SUM(column1) just repopulates the prior value according the the column2 value.... defeating the purpose of my SUM.

Help?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

Use a full explicit subquery to obtain the sum of column1:

```
SELECT column2,
       column1 / (SELECT SUM(column1) FROM Tablea)
FROM Tablea
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use sum windowing function - Sum(column1) over() -- Gives total sum

```
SELECT column2, column1/(SUM(column1) OVER()) FROM YourTable
```